# Getting distinct value for a field in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a database collection and this is its document structure.

```
{
_id: ObjectId("xxxxddsdsfdfdfdf")
category: electronics
sku: 10902
}

{
_id: ObjectId("dfdfdgfsdfdsgsf")
category: apparels
sku: 90345
}

{
_id: ObjectId("sdfdfdsggfgsgsdgsgsf")
category: electronics
sku: 10345
}

{
_id: ObjectId("dfndsnfkjdfdfsdnfsdf")
category: electronics
sku: 43435
}
```

I am trying to find the total number of SKUs per category. **It should eliminate duplication and keep the values distinct**. For example, `electronics: 3, apparels: 1`.

I have written a query, but it is giving me a total number of SKUs across categories which is not at all intended.

```
db.ecomm_sku_count.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                category: '$category',
                sku_count: '$sku'
            },
            total_sku: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $count: "total_sku_units"
    }
])

#output= [ { total_sku_units: 4 } ]
```

The intended output must be somewhat like this.

```
[
  { _id: { category: 'electronics', sku_count: 3 } },
  { _id: { category: 'apparels', sku_count: 1} }
]
```

I am trying to find the distinct SKU values per category.

I am beginner to mongo aggregation framework. Pardon me if the question is of noob type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the below code is what you are looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "category": "$category",
        
      },
      "total_sku": {
        "$addToSet": "$sku"
      }
    },
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "total_sku": {
        "$size": "$total_sku"
      }
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xGn2N7uciMK)

Comment: hi…it is counting duplicates too. the result is not distinct

Comment: @KrisT Apologise for the inconvenience, I have updated the answer. Check if this is what you are looking for.